# How do you get from the polarisation operator to particle current?

Tags: condensed-matter, density-operator, second-quantization

I'm going through Mahan's "Many Particle Physics", and I'm a bit confused about his reasoning.  He introduces the polarisation operator as
$$\textbf{P}=\int\textbf{r}\rho(\textbf{r})d^3r$$
he then says "recall that the time derivative of the polarisation is the particle current"
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\textbf{P}=\int\textbf{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho(\textbf{r},t)d^3r$$
which I'm guessing is because the position operator is time independent (measuring probability at a fixed point and all).  He then states that this can be "proved easily" by using the equation of continuity, followed by an integration by parts
\begin{align}
 \dot{\rho}(\textbf{r},t)&=-\nabla\cdot\textbf{j}(\textbf{r},t)\\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\textbf{P}&=-\int\textbf{r}\nabla\cdot\textbf{j}(\textbf{r},t)d^3r=\int\textbf{j}(\textbf{r})\cdot\nabla\textbf{r}d^3r\\
 &=\int\textbf{j}(\textbf{r},t)d^3r
\end{align}
I can follow the second step (assuming that the $\textbf{r}$ is an abuse of notation and is not actually a vector), but I can't see at all how the $\nabla\textbf{r}$ drops out, or why the $\int\nabla\cdot(\textbf{r}\textbf{j})d^3r$ term vanishes from the integration by parts.  This is the first time he's talked about polarisation, and everything I find online is either about light or EM fields in matter.

Could someone please explain what he has done here please?  As well as making sure I've explained the earlier parts correctly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\vec\nabla\vec r=\mathbb I$ pretty much by definition, and the integration by parts surface term vanishes because for every physical current going in whatever direction, the positions cancel in opposing pairs. I mean, imagine that this surface is a gigantic sphere, and you would have this cancellation.

Comment: My issue with the $\nabla\textbf{r}=\mathbb{I}$ thing is that shouldn't the result be a vector?  The integral would be the dot product of $\textbf{j}$ with a vector $\mathbb{I}$, which would give a scalar, which then couldn't be the current operator since that operator should give a vector as a result (i.e. the RHS is not a vector).

Comment: I have chosen to write the RHS as an identity matrix because it is the identity matrix. The dot product of a vector with the identity matrix is going to give you a vector, which is what you needed.

Comment: Could you explain a bit why it's the identity matrix?  I thought $\nabla$ always gave a vector as an output, e.g. in spherical coords where $\textbf{r}=r\hat{r}$, $\nabla\textbf{r}=(1,0,0)$ in the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ basis.  I thought only the total derivative $D$ gave a matrix as an output?

Comment: Consider the differentiation to act leftwords in: $$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end  {pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\partial_x&\partial_y&\partial_z\end  {pmatrix}=\mathbb I$$

Comment: Let me phrase it a bit differently, we get the integration by parts from taking the volume integral from the chain rule identity $\nabla\cdot(f\textbf{v})=f(\nabla\cdot\textbf{v})+\textbf{v}\cdot\nabla f$, where $f$ is a scalar function and $\textbf{v}$ is a vector field.  Since the LHS is the divergence, we know that it is scalar.  Therefore, shouldn't both sides be the volume integral of a scalar?

Comment: Your point is correct; however, you know that the integral is going to return you a vector, so you should be starting with a version of the identity that returns you a vector too. This is kind of the situation whereby the basic physics mathematics is just totally insufficient to disambiguate, and you do get much more clarity if you go into better maths, like differential geometry.